# www.superuser.com down, superuser.com not down

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

I just quickly said this in chat, only two people were active and one person had the error, one person did not. I also tried it via hidemyass and it works fine, so I have no idea what is going wrong.

For me, going to [`http://www.superuser.com`](http://www.superuser.com) redirects to `http://www.superuser.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/` and a generic asp.net error page of `Server Error in '/' Application.`

Going to [`http://superuser.com`](http://superuser.com) works fine.

I have just tried `http://www.stackoverflow.com` and it redirects without the www just fine.

I have not seen any maintenance banners and as it doesn't seem to be for everyone, I just thought I should bring this to TPTB in case of some error.

---

Edit, same result on ServerFault pages.

Comment: heheh, redirection fail?

Comment: `[status-norepro]` in Chrome 11.0.696.3 dev.

Comment: What OS/browser? What IPs are they pointing to?

Comment: @TmoWij - I have this in Chrome and Firefox - nslookup/ping returns the same IP for me as for people where it is working fine.

Comment: I see the error here, using Firefox 3.6. I wonder what Chrome does differently?

Comment: Reproduced in Firefox 3.6.15 on Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: Also reproduced in Google Chrome 10.0.648.133 on Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: Reproduced in Internet Explorer 8 on Windows 7 running in VirtualBox 4.0.4.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We had an IIS server in the pool that wasn't re-directing correctly. I've recycled the server and it is redirecting correctly now.

I'm looking into how we can prevent this in the future.

Comment: Hah! So it was MicroSoft software after all. Do you [believe him  now?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82818/www-stackoverflow-com-down-again)

Comment: @Pekka - Brilliant link!

Comment: @Zypher - cool... The only reason I posted it was because someone said they could and I knew I couldn't (when I was sure everything was working... I have answered so many questions when it turns out to be someones internet!) but the fact that a proxy worked really confused me.... Should these things in the future be reported or just leave it up to you lot as I am sure you monitor stuff anyway?

Comment: @Wil please report them, while we do monitor things monitoring is never perfect like I would never have known where to look for this specific error if you hadn't reported it. Now we have alerts for it and everybody is better off :)

Comment: @Zypher - ok, cool!

Comment: @Wil re the link, I have given up trying to figure out what goes on in that man's mind.

Comment: @Pekka - What is more scary is reading his profile! How on earth can someone have views like that being in IT for 30+ years... and Why can I still not find a good job considering he has!

Comment: @Wil that is what totally boggles my mind too. He must have a *very* safe position somewhere  or be so good in his field that clients *have* to put up with him :)

Comment: @Pekka hahaha!!